# Validation error in Jalali/persian date

Tags: c#, datetime, persian

I am developing application in Arabic/Dari/Pashto (for Afghanistan) using C# and also using Jalali/Persian calendar for date selection. I want to validate input date before saving into database. I am using below function for validation and passing Jalali/Persian calendar date to this function. It works perfectly when user select date something like "28/02/1393" but it throws error for date "31/02/1393". Both dates are valid Jalali/Persian date.

I think this issue is happenning because somehow application considering this date is English and there is no any 31st day in 2nd month in English calendar. Please help me to find solution for that.

```
static public bool ValidateParsianDate(string date)
{
    bool status = true;

    try
    {
        PersianCalendar persianCalendar = new PersianCalendar();
        CultureInfo persianCulture = new CultureInfo("fa-IR");
        DateTime persianDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy", persianCulture);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string msg = ex.Message;
        status = false;
    }

    return status;
}
```

Thanks & Regards,

Rajeev

Comment: +1 date/time issues are one of the biggest problems for computer science and software engineering IMO

Answer (score 1):

Use the `PersianCalendar.ToDateTime(
    int year,
    int month,
    int day,
    int hour,
    int minute,
    int second,
    int millisecond,
    int era
)` method.

```
static public bool ValidateParsianDate(string date)
{
    bool status = true;

    try
    {
        PersianCalendar persianCalendar = new PersianCalendar();
        var dateParts = date.Split(new char[] { '/' }).Select(d=> int.Parse(d)).ToArray();
        var date = persianCalendar.ToDateTime(dateParts[2], dateParts[1], dateParts[0], 0, 0,0,0, /*8 era of year here **/);
 }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string msg = ex.Message;
        status = false;
    }

    return status;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `persianCulture.Calendar` is set to `GregorianCalendar` by default in .NET framework and can't be changed to `PersianCalendar` without using the reflection. [more info here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32096/How-to-Set-PersianCalendar-to-CultureInfo)

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem but i used this and it work

```
public static bool IsValidDate(string date)
    {
        var regex = new Regex("^\\d{ 4 } /\\d{ 2}/\\d{ 2}$");
        var arrPattern = new[] {
            new Regex("^\\d{4}/\\d{2}/\\d{2}$"),
            new Regex("^\\d{ 4 } /\\d{ 2}/\\d{ 1}$"),
            new Regex("^\\d{ 4 } /\\d{ 1}/\\d{ 2}$"),
            new Regex("^\\d{ 4 } /\\d{ 1}/\\d{ 1}$"),
            new Regex("^\\d{ 2 } /\\d{ 2}/\\d{ 2}$"),
            new Regex("^\\d{ 2 } /\\d{ 2}/\\d{ 1}$"),
            new Regex("^\\d{ 2 } /\\d{ 1}/\\d{ 2}$"),
            new Regex("^\\d{ 2 } /\\d{ 1}/\\d{ 1}")
        };
        const int kabise = 1387;
        var year = 0;
        var mounth = 0;
        var day = 0; var flag = false;
        foreach (var t in arrPattern)
        {
            if (t.IsMatch(date))
                flag = true;
        }
        if (flag == false) return flag;
        //جدا کننده تاریخ می تواند یکی از این کاراکترها باشد
        var splitDate = date.Split('/','-',':');
        year = Convert.ToInt32(splitDate[0]);
        mounth = Convert.ToInt32(splitDate[1]);
        day = Convert.ToInt32(splitDate[2]);
        if (mounth > 12 || mounth <= 0)
            flag = false;
        else
        {
            if (mounth< 7)
            {
                if (day > 31)
                {
                    flag = false;
                }
            }
            if (mounth != 12) return flag;
            var t = (year - kabise) % 4;
            if ((year - kabise) % 4 == 0)
            {
                if (day >= 31)
                    flag = false;
            }
            else if (day >= 30)
                flag = false;
        }
        return flag;
    }
```